# Delay passing logger options to FastifyAdapter in Nest.js

Tags: logging, nestjs, fastify

I use Fastify instead of Express in my Nest.js application and I'd like to configure logging for Fastify. The configuration for logging (and many other things) is provided by `ConfigService`. However, services are available only after creating Nest's `app` object but I have to provide logger options earlier - while creating it. It looks like this:

```js
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
      AppModule,
      new FastifyAdapter(loggerConfig)
    );
    const config = app.get('ConfigService') as ConfigService;
```

How could I use ConfigService to provide `loggerConfig` to `FastifyAdapter`? Is there a way to delay logger setup with Fastify or perhaps a way to get the service before `app` is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this problem with Nest's Application Context:

```js
    async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
      const ctx = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
      const config = ctx.get('ConfigService') as ConfigService;
      const logger = ctx.get('LoggerService') as LoggerService;
      await ctx.close();

      const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
        AppModule,
        new FastifyAdapter({ logger: logger.log })
      );
      ...
    }
    bootstrap();
```

**But I find it ugly**. Just see: first I create the ApplicationContext to get services out of it, then I have to close it so that it doesn't occupy the database connection, then create the Application that uses the container holding the same services I created and destroyed previously.

Ideally, there would be a way to turn ApplicationContext into NestFastifyApplication. If anyone knows how to do it or just has better idea how to implement it - you are welcome. I won't accept my own answer any time soon.

Comment: Since it seems there is no other way, I'll accept my own answer

Comment: Now you should write `ctx.get(ConfigService)` rather than `ctx.get('ConfigService') as ConfigService`